# Upload multiple images to separate folder in Next Js

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, react-hooks, next.js, multipartform-data

I am working on a Next Js front-end application that has to upload multiple images to a particular folder. When I upload images it gives an error as it has "Internal Server Error"

This is what I have done so far in the front-end,

```
import React from "react";

export default function UploadImage() {
const [imgsSrc, setImgsSrc] = React.useState([]);

const uploadToClient = (e) => {
    for (const file of e.target.files) {
        setImgsSrc((imgs) => [...imgs, file]);
    }
};

const uploadToServer = async () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    for (const file of imgsSrc) {
        formData.append('image', file, file.name)
    }    
    const response = await fetch("/api/upload", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    });
};

return(
  <div>
    <h3>Upload photos</h3>
    <input onChange={uploadToClient} type="file" name="file" multiple />

    <div>
      {imgsSrc.map((link) => (
         <img src={link} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
      ))}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onClick={uploadToServer}>Send to server</button>
  </div>
    )
}
```

And this is the code for '/api/upload/

```
import formidable from "formidable";
import path from "path";
import { renameSync } from "fs";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async function upload(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(405).json({ error: "Method not allowed" });
  }

  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
    keepExtensions: true,
    maxFileSize: 200 * 1024 * 1024,
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
        return resolve();
      }

      if (!files.image) {
        res.status(422).json({ error: "Bad request: missing image field" });
        return resolve();
      }

      const ext = path.extname(files.image.path);
      const uuid = Math.random().toString(26).slice(2);
      await renameSync(files.image.path, `./public/images/${uuid}${ext}`);

      res.status(201).json({
        uuid,
        url: `/images/${uuid}${ext}`,
      });
      return resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

I am getting this error when I upload images

body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/upload"

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What error are you seeing on the server (check the terminal where you started your dev server)?

Comment: unhandledRejection: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Comment: That's most likely thrown by the `renameSync` call, in the `upload` handler. You should debug that code and check if all the values passed to it are correct.

Comment: I have made some changes in the code and now I am getting "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined". Any guess?

Comment: That's the same error as before. What code changes did you make? Can you please update your question?

Comment: @juliomalves, I updated the question. Changed 'uploadToServer'.